# Python run .py in separate windows (Windows 7, Python 2.6.6 64-bit)

Tags: python, cmd

I have no idea why python run every script in a new command window.

For example I run: `python testfile.py`, it is show new window and close immediately, so I can't look the traceback.

Python 2.7 32-bit at the same machine works normally

Comment: This does not seem to be the norm, I have python from windows to linux, they all start at the same window. It looks more like a system setting. Are you using windows? if so, try navigate to the python home folder, and start python.exe there. (e.g. cd c:/python27) EDIT: my bad, i didn't notice you had listed windows as OS already, please ignore that question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `raw_input()` at the end of `testfile.py` ?

Comment: No raw_input() isn't, that I want. I mean even if I run easy_install ... or pip ..., or paster ... If it fails and I can't see why, because window closed.

Answer (score 0):

- You can run it through IDLE, the built-in editor. It may not be much helpful if you have to provide command-line args.
- An alternate option may be making the code wait for a keypress using `raw_input()`, as Insidi0us said.
- You can also print the errors to a file.
- Another option may be running the command prompt first, then run `python` command (make sure your environment variable contains the python installation directory).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cmd window to stay open, add the -i command line switch to python.

This explains an easy way to do it.

https://superuser.com/questions/256759/adding-default-command-line-options-when-opening-a-particular-filetype

Here's documentation for -i

> -i     : inspect interactively after running script, (also PYTHONINSPECT=x)
>            and force prompts, even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal

Comment: Well, thats really a different problem, because that's not simply a matter of windows default program handler launching your program.  An executable "just runs".

if you're easy installing something, you can't really just run that program anyway, you have to provide an argument - 

easy_install something

Comment: After rereading your problem, I misunderstood it.  If you're running python from the command line, it shouldn't launch a new window each time.  Uninstall / reinstall may fix it...